# What thing i need to install Webmatrix on offline system?

Tags: installation, webmatrix

I want to install Webmatrix in a offline system. Are their anywhere a list i can see to have for instlling them without a thing like ["you need this for this and this for this"].

means i need a list of component and stuff i need to have to install them without any kind of problem in offline system. whereever a problem may be come and because no internet i can't install a require thing if Webmatrix tell me to get them from internet.

Are their anyone can know the thing i need to have to install them in offline system.

Answer (score 0):

You need following to install WebMatrix.

1. .Net Framework 4.0
2. IIS Express 7.5
3. WebPI 3.0
   (Below given are optional)
4. Microsoft asp.net MVC 3 (http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)
5. Microsoft asp.net Web Pages (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=300314da-dedd-4540-a236-a0de0a5a534d)